# sslsocket read only once from inputstream,why?

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, sslsocketfactory

Part of the connection to the server is complete, but can not always read data from inputstream and can only be read once.

```
    public void startSSLClient() throws IOException {
    inf = new Inflater();
    mSocketBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSslSocket.getInputStream()));
    new Thread() {
        boolean online =false;
        String s;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while ( true ) {
                    String str = mSocketBufferReader.readLine();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
                        Logger.e("PacketReader","process packet : "+str);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

If I try this, it's working that always read from inputstream.

```
    public void startSSLClient() throws IOException {
    inf = new Inflater();

    new Thread() {
        boolean online =false;
        String s;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while ( true ) {
                    BufferedReader mSocketBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSslSocket.getInputStream()));
                    String str = mSocketBufferReader.readLine();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
                        Logger.e("PacketReader","process packet : "+str);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I don't know the reason. I just want to use a global field. I don't want to always use a new local field.

Comment: Unclear what your problem is, or what a global field has to do with it. You do need to check the result `readLine()` for null, and exit the read loop when you get it. And you should not use a new buffered reader every time around the loop.

Comment: @EJP `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str))` is check the result for null. I want to read data from inputstream always. I can read by first time. Then I send my keeplive message to server and the server responded to the client.

Comment: And it also checks it for empty, and you aren't exiting the loop if you get null. You don't want to exit if it is merely empty (`""`). What you have is not adequate. The usual way to write that loop is `while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)`.

Comment: @EJP But I can not read the response data by `readLine()`.This method is only for testing purposes。

Comment: Still unclear what you're talking about. If `readLine()` isn't the right method to call, why are you calling it?

Comment: @EJP Like a chat software, I need to keep reading messages sent to me by the server.The second way I can always read the data, but the first way can only be read once.

Comment: @EJP `startSSLClient()` is just for test my problem.I will optimize it by solve this problem

Comment: The second way cannot possibly work. You will lose data every time you throw away a buffered reader. Still totally obscure what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BufferedReader mSocketBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSslSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Take that out of the loop. You can execute that statement only once for a connection.

Comment: yeah, you are right and this is my first code.But it can only be read once from inputstream.Them message is coming, the bufferReader can not read.

Comment: @DrDemon What message? The JDK doesn't output any such message.